# MetaBox Layout for all users

Tags: metabox

I was wondering : You are an administrator : when you re-order the layout of your meta-box, in a page, or in a post, this layout is saved with your user profil : for example you drag the category box before the publish box...

Is it possible to save this layout for other users (editors, authors..) ?

Is it possible to organize your layout for every kind of users, without logging with their account ?

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Was any of this answer useful, did they solve your issue. If so, choose the answer that helped you and accept that answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is a rough outline but something like this should work:

1. Assume there is a some "master" user with a known user ID-- your
   administrator or a user created for this purpose.
2. When meta boxes are displayed, [user settings are checked](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L899) to see
   if boxes have been moved around.
3. You can [interrupt that check with a filter on
   `get_user_option_{$option}`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L261).

Put that together:

```
function force_user_option_wpse_124330($option) {
  remove_filter('get_user_option_meta-box-order_post','force_user_option_wpse_124330');
  return get_user_option('meta-box-order_post', 1); // 1 is the known user ID
}
add_filter('get_user_option_meta-box-order_post','force_user_option_wpse_124330');
```

I have serious misgivings about doing this at all. It could well cause confusion for your users. Even if that sketch of filter works, or you can make it work, I'd consider disabling the metabox dragging for any but the "master" user.

You will have to do something very similar for other pages with meta boxes that you want to hijack.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup a different default layout by hooking into [`do_meta_boxes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_meta_boxes), take a look here:

- [How to change default position of WP meta boxes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33063/how-to-change-default-position-of-wp-meta-boxes)

Or you could use the global variable `$wp_meta_boxes` to do so:

- [Get List of Registered Meta Boxes and Removing Them](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56104/get-list-of-registered-meta-boxes-and-removing-them)
- [How to Remove Certain Screen Options and Meta Boxes from add/edit post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56606/how-to-remove-certain-screen-options-and-meta-boxes-from-add-edit-post-type)
- [How to set wordpress metabox position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709811/how-to-set-wordpress-metabox-position)
- [Dashboard Widgets API - Example - Advanced: Forcing your widget to the top](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced:_Forcing_your_widget_to_the_top)

Although the last two links are about dashboard widgets, there is little to none difference in how it is done for meta boxes on edit screens. Doing it with either method would be of course setting this up programmatically. You'd still have to disable the dragging and dropping I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sorting behavior of ordering the metaboxes.

`add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context,
         $priority, $callback_args );`

There are priorities (`$priority`) to display. My Idea is to give all of them same priority but keep their id's in sorted manner.

For example: If I want *c_meta_box* to be displayed before *b_meta_box* then i will register my meta boxes something like this.

```
add_meta_box('a_c_meta_box','C META BOX','c_meta_box_cb','post','normal','default');
add_meta_box('b_b_meta_box','B META BOX','b_meta_box_cb','post','normal','default');
```

Notice: How i have changed the id's of the boxes and added a_ and b_ to sort them. You can add numbers too. Giving all of them same `$priority` but sorted id's.

I know this is not the perfect solution but it works in this scenario.

For trouble shooting you can use this code to see look at the `global $wp_meta_boxes` like this:

```
global $wp_meta_boxes;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wp_meta_boxes);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Further References: [Widget API Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API)

NOTE: After making changes on existing metaboxes hit Publish Button once to save the meta box's changed id's.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is sort of bad practice as you're taking control out of users' hands and may confuse them, but I also understand that many users don't use this feature and/or are hopelessly bad with technology and end up screwing up the interface for themselves (for instance by collapsing meta boxes... different usermeta option for that but identical idea). We also know that hardcoding this stuff is bad practice but sometimes you really just need to get that shit done:

```
add_filter('get_user_option_meta-box-order_post', 'override_post_meta_box_order');

function override_post_meta_box_order($order) {
    $order['normal'] = "comma,separated,list,of,meta,boxes";
    $order['side'] = "you,get,the,idea";

    return $order;
}
```

You can find out what values to use here by peeking into your database or `error_log(print_r($order,true))` or whatever.

A MUCH better way would be to get these values from another account, like your admin account, which you can then use to control and modify the meta box order. @s_ha_dum's answer goes for exactly this except that you get an infinite loop in it, as every call to `get_user_option()` goes through your filter, which in turn calls `get_user_option()`, etc... You need to have a base case, which checks if the requested user is 1 then actually return the user option. You can't simply check `get_current_user_id()` though because that will still return the current user viewing the page, even if you're calling `get_user_option('meta-box-order_post', 1)`. I'm sure there's a way but briefly looking I couldn't figure out how to avoid this infinite loop.

Actually one way around it would be to directly query `$wpdb` for this value instead of using the WordPress function `get_user_option()`.

**EDIT**: With the bug fixed, @s_ha_dum's answer is better, as it doesn't hard-code the order but lets a designated user control it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124337/41534

Comment: Well, I did say it was untested. :) I believe it should work better now.

Comment: Aha I forgot about `remove_filter()`! Clever.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It bugs me when my stuff doesn't work :)

Comment: No problem. I'm using that code now in production by the way, and it works like a charm.